# how to save file in background thread using Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, multithreading

I'm trying to make an application that uses a web service to get some data from a directory, but I also need to save the data into the device, include images, to do so I'm using **Alamofire** and **AlamofireImage** framework for consuming the webservice. I save the generated objects in a database with **Realm** framework and for images I save the **UIImage** into a file.

Basically, the ViewController has a tableView which displays de data, but it seems laggy because of the images writing into files.

This is my writing function:

```
func saveImage(_ image: UIImage) {
    if let data = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image) {
        let name = "images/person_directory_\(id).png"
        let docsDir = getDocumentsDirectory()
        let filename = docsDir.appendingPathComponent(name)
        let fm = FileManager.default

        if !fm.fileExists(atPath: docsDir.appendingPathComponent("images").path) {
            do {
                try fm.createDirectory(at: docsDir.appendingPathComponent("images"), withIntermediateDirectories: true, attributes: nil)
                try data.write(to: filename)
                try! realm?.write {
                    self.imageLocal = name
                }
            }
            catch {
                print(error)
            }
        }
        else {
            do {
                try data.write(to: filename, options: .atomic)
                try! realm?.write {
                    self.imageLocal = name
                }
            }
            catch {
                print(error)
            }

        }
    }
}
```

I call this function when **Alamofire** downloads the image

```
if person.imageLocal != nil,  let image = person.loadLocalImage() {
        print("Load form disk: \(person.imageLocal)")
        cell.imgProfile.image = image
    }
    else if !(person.image?.isEmpty)! {
        Alamofire.request(person.image!).responseImage(completionHandler: { (response) in
            if response.result.isSuccess {
                if let image = response.result.value {
                    person.saveImage(image)
                    cell.imgProfile.image = image
                    print("Downloaded: \(person.imageLocal)")
                }
            }
        })
    }
```

But the tableView looks laggy when scrolled and I was trying to make the writing operation into a diferent thread so it could get written without affecting the application performance by using **DispatchQeue**

```
DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background).async {
                    do {
                        try data.write(to: filename)
                    }
                    catch {
                        print(error)
                    }
                }
```

But even so the applications stills laggy.

UPDATE:

I tryed this as Rob suggested:

```
func saveImage(_ image: UIImage) {
    if let data = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image) {
        let name = "images/person_directory_\(id).png"
        do {
            try realm?.write {
                self.imageLocal = name
            }
        }
        catch {
            print("Realm error")
        }
        DispatchQueue.global().async {
            let docsDir = self.getDocumentsDirectory()
            let filename = docsDir.appendingPathComponent(name)
            let fm = FileManager.default

            if !fm.fileExists(atPath: docsDir.appendingPathComponent("images").path) {
                do {
                    try fm.createDirectory(at: docsDir.appendingPathComponent("images"), withIntermediateDirectories: true, attributes: nil)
                }
                catch {
                    print(error)
                }
            }
            do {
                try data.write(to: filename)
            }
            catch {
                print(error)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I can't dispatch the Realm writing becase Realm doesn't suport multithreading.
It stills scrolling laggy but not as much as the first time.

Comment: You might want to adjust your title to this question, because you have the correct code for writing in the background.

Comment: What do you mean by "laggy"? Is your main thread laggy, i.e. the table scrolls kind of funny, or is it just that that images aren't showing up in the table the way you expect them to? Also something I see is that you're keeping a reference to the table cell in the AlamoFire.request() closure -- if you have a lot of cells and the user scrolls, that cell might get re-used. Maybe keep the index of the cell instead, and reload the cell once you have the image.

Comment: To expand on joeybladb's question, is the issue that the image doesn't appear immediately (you can consider fixing that by specifying a [`prefetchDataSource`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uitableview/1771763-prefetchdatasource)) or that the scrolling not smooth (i.e. it stutters)?

Comment: The issue is that the table view doesn`t scroll smooth, after the images gets saved once it runs perfectly but not the first time and the problem is that it could update frecuently.

Comment: Are you sure it's the `data.write()` that is causing the hitch in the scroll and not something else (like writing to realm, or subsequent reads while realm is busy)? I'd try commenting that out `data.write()` and make sure. If you dispatch that asynchronously to a global queue, I find it really hard to imagine that it would cause the problem in question. Also, are you testing this on actual device or simulator?

Comment: Unrelated to your question, this pattern of asynchronously updating the cell can be problematic. Try using the network link conditioner to simulate a really bad network connection and scroll quickly. I suspect you'll see images temporarily change to the wrong image. We often use the AlamofireImage `UIImageView` category to avoid that problem. Or, at the very least, make sure that the cell for that index path is still visible before trying to update.

Comment: I think @Rob is correct -- you may want to dispatch the code in the `if response.result.isSuccess { ... }` block on the global queue. I bet that would fix it.

Comment: I did what @Rob said but Realm doesn't support multithreading

Comment: @mangasaske What I would do is run the app on Instruments Time Profiler, download hundreds of pictures, and scroll back and forth for half a minute just to get a sense of where the bottleneck is. That actually should've been my first suggestion, because otherwise we're just shooting rubber bands in the dark.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So the proper answer as @Rob gave it is

```
   DispatchQueue.global().async {
      do {
         try data.write(to: filename)
      }
      catch {
         print(error)
      }
    }
```

But just as important is to never use a reference to a UITableViewCell from an asynchronous call (again credit @Rob). For example, setting a cell value from the asynchronous parts of your code.

```
                cell.imgProfile.image = image
```

UITableViewCells are re-used, so you don't know that the original cell is still used at the same index. For a test, scroll your list really fast so your images get loaded, if you see images appear in the wrong cell, its the re-use problem.

So from an asynchronous callback you need to figure out if the cell index for the new image is visible, go get the current cell for that index to set it's image. If the index isn't visible, then store/cache the image until it's index is scrolled into view. At that point it's cell will be created with UITableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath, and you can set the image there.